# What does "Computed -srcwin falls outside raster size" mean when clipping?

Tags: qgis, raster, sqlite

What does the following mean, when I try to clip and save the result as a sqlite or other format?

> Computed -srcwin falls outside raster size of 7807x4771

Answer (score 1):

If you clip a raster on a vector layer, both must have the same coordinate reference system.

It is not enough to `Set CRS for layer` in QGIS, because clipping is an external command.

Best practice is to look up the CRS of the raster, then rightclick on the vector layer -> Save As ... , apply the CRS of the raster to a new shapefile, and add that to the canvas.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think that I am only clipping a raster layer. I did have another vector layer over the top but have now removed it and...same message appears.

Comment: Usually you clip a raster by a polygon vector layer, or enter bounding coordinates manually. Please explain in detail what you did. Perhaps you can upload your raster layer somewhere as well.